# How to improve the write speed of mongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database, nosql

I use mongo and sys-ng to save my log

the log is about 20000 lines pre second

I run mongo whit 2 `shard` and 3 `host` with mongos

I write  a python script in `ipython`

```
In [48]: %time dddd=[qlogdb.insert({'tet':1313232,'test':1232423,'asdasds':'sdadsds'})  for i in range(100000)]
CPU times: user 7.24 s, sys: 2.51 s, total: 9.75 s
Wall time: 10.77 s
```

I think it can write 10000 line pre second from the output log

I Need to improve the write speed when insert data to `mongo`

I want to try use  Multiple processes when i insert data to `mongo`

but i‘m not sure if it  can   improve the write speed ；

any way ?

Comment: What's the bottleneck on mongo? You can likely figure this out by running mongostat on the primary member of each shard. The answer depends entirely on what's spiking.

Answer (score 2):

You require 100,000 write/second and you don't have any requirements on reading the data, i.e.

- You don't need the data to be consistent by a certain time threshold.
- You don't have any reliability requirements, i.e. you don't care if you lose the data because N servers crash, and you don't need the writer to know whether the writes were successful.

That being said, there are two pieces of advice I have:

1. Alleviate the I/O bottleneck through the use of [RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID), e.g. RAID 0. This assumes your load is I/O bound; however, your benchmark is also slightly CPU intensive because of the work required to create all the dictionaries.
2. Use batch inserts:

   ```
   In [1]: %time return_value = [collection.insert({'tet':1313232,'test':1232423,'asdasds':'sdadsds'})  for i in xrange(100000)]
   CPU times: user 7.00 s, sys: 0.85 s, total: 7.85 s
   Wall time: 7.86 s

   In [2]: %time return_value = [collection.insert({'tet':1313232,'test':1232423,'asdasds':'sdadsds'})  for i in xrange(100000)]
   CPU times: user 6.79 s, sys: 0.84 s, total: 7.63 s
   Wall time: 7.64 s

   In [3]: documents = [{'tet':1313232,'test':1232423,'asdasds':'sdadsds'} for i in xrange(100000)]
   In [10]: %time return_value = collection.insert(documents)
   CPU times: user 0.97 s, sys: 0.03 s, total: 0.99 s
   Wall time: 1.00 s

   In [4]: documents = [{'tet':1313232,'test':1232423,'asdasds':'sdadsds'} for i in xrange(100000)]
   In [10]: %time return_value = collection.insert(documents)
   CPU times: user 0.92 s, sys: 0.04 s, total: 0.96 s
   Wall time: 0.98 s
   ```

Please note that I replaced your `range` call with `xrange`.

Of course if you have read requirements as well then you need to consult the [pymongo collection.insert](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert) docs with respect to `safe` and `w` parameters.  No such thing as a free lunch etc.

Hope this helps!